# ValueError at /complete/steam/ : invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'name'

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I recently created a Custom User as follows and have it installed:

**steamuser**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    steamid = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_mod = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    reputation = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, default=0)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'steamid'

    objects = UserManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.steamid

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
```

I have also created the UserManager functions create_user and create_superuser.

I have set the User model to my custom model for both django and python-social

**settings**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'steamuser.User'
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'steamuser.User'
```

In the social backends file for steam I have changed it to include just two details (for now)

**steam.py**

```
    details = {'steamid': player.get('steamid'),
                'username': player.get('personaname'),
```

When I attempt to login and it redirects back to the landing page (home) I receive the following error

> ValueError at /complete/steam/
>   invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'evolve'

I am looking at the traceback but I am not sure where the error could be originating from since its obviously some issue with my User model and python social.

**EDIT**

Here is the **view** for complete/steam (from python-social app)

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

from social.actions import do_auth, do_complete, do_disconnect
from social.apps.django_app.utils import strategy


@strategy('social:complete')
def auth(request, backend):
    return do_auth(request.social_strategy, redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME)


@csrf_exempt
@strategy('social:complete')
def complete(request, backend, *args, **kwargs):
    """Authentication complete view, override this view if transaction
    management doesn't suit your needs."""
    return do_complete(request.social_strategy, _do_login, request.user,
                       redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the function do_complete from social actions

```
def do_complete(strategy, login, user=None, redirect_name='next',
            *args, **kwargs):
# pop redirect value before the session is trashed on login()
data = strategy.request_data()
redirect_value = strategy.session_get(redirect_name, '') or \
                 data.get(redirect_name, '')

is_authenticated = user_is_authenticated(user)
user = is_authenticated and user or None

partial = partial_pipeline_data(strategy, user, *args, **kwargs)
if partial:
    xargs, xkwargs = partial
    user = strategy.continue_pipeline(*xargs, **xkwargs)
else:
    user = strategy.complete(user=user, request=strategy.request,
                             *args, **kwargs)

if user and not isinstance(user, strategy.storage.user.user_model()):
    return user

if is_authenticated:
    if not user:
        url = setting_url(strategy, redirect_value, 'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL')
    else:
        url = setting_url(strategy, redirect_value,
                          'NEW_ASSOCIATION_REDIRECT_URL',
                          'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL')
elif user:
    if user_is_active(user):
        # catch is_new/social_user in case login() resets the instance
        is_new = getattr(user, 'is_new', False)
        social_user = user.social_user
        login(strategy, user, social_user)
        # store last login backend name in session
        strategy.session_set('social_auth_last_login_backend',
                             social_user.provider)

        if is_new:
            url = setting_url(strategy,
                              'NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL',
                              redirect_value,
                              'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL')
        else:
            url = setting_url(strategy, redirect_value,
                              'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL')
    else:
        url = setting_url(strategy, 'INACTIVE_USER_URL', 'LOGIN_ERROR_URL',
                          'LOGIN_URL')
else:
    url = setting_url(strategy, 'LOGIN_ERROR_URL', 'LOGIN_URL')

if redirect_value and redirect_value != url:
    redirect_value = quote(redirect_value)
    url += ('?' in url and '&' or '?') + \
           '{0}={1}'.format(redirect_name, redirect_value)

if strategy.setting('SANITIZE_REDIRECTS', True):
    url = sanitize_redirect(strategy.request_host(), url) or \
          strategy.setting('LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL')
return strategy.redirect(url)
```

Here is the traceback

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/steam/?janrain_nonce=2014-08-11T01%3A11%3A40Zk6fuhG&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Flogin&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561197977746283&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561197977746283&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fcomplete%2Fsteam%2F%3Fjanrain_nonce%3D2014-08-11T01%253A11%253A40Zk6fuhG&openid.response_nonce=2014-08-11T01%3A11%3A42ZXa1zGqR0YX6vKkOzBDlc70yZJj8%3D&openid.assoc_handle=1234567890&openid.signed=signed%2Cop_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle&openid.sig=%2FhtMIPXfOG16fnfimXZ0Vsb5NNU%3D

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'steamuser',
 'social.apps.django_app.default',
 'south',
 'dota2items')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\apps\django_app\utils.py" in wrapper
  45.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\apps\django_app\views.py" in complete
  21.                        redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\actions.py" in do_complete
  44.                                  *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\strategies\base.py" in complete
  71.         return self.backend.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\backends\open_id.py" in auth_complete
  165.         return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\strategies\django_strategy.py" in authenticate
  71.         return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in authenticate
  49.             user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\backends\base.py" in authenticate
  69.         return self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\backends\base.py" in pipeline
  72.         out = self.run_pipeline(pipeline, pipeline_index, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\backends\base.py" in run_pipeline
  98.             result = func(*args, **out) or {}
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\pipeline\user.py" in get_username
  48.         while storage.user.user_exists(username=final_username):
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\social\storage\django_orm.py" in user_exists
  49.         return cls.user_model().objects.filter(*args, **kwargs).count() > 0
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in filter
  163.         return self.get_queryset().filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  593.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  611.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1204.         clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1240.                     current_negated=current_negated)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1131.         clause.add(constraint, AND)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\utils\tree.py" in add
  104.         data = self._prepare_data(data)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py" in _prepare_data
  79.             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py" in prepare
  352.             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  1085.         return super(IntegerField, self).get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  369.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\steamtest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1079.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /complete/steam/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'evolve'
```

Comment: and where is the traceback? your problem is that you are casting a string to an int.

Comment: Cound you paste the view and urls code for `"/complete/steam/"`

Comment: ive added the information requested. thanks

Comment: What's the value of your user manager?